# Задача о перемещении шахматного коня на доске

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, динамические-массивы, графы

Вводятся начальные и конечные координаты положения шахматного коня 
(x1[1..8], y1[1..8], x2[1..8], y2[1..8]). Нужно написать программу, определяющую за сколько ходов конь переместится в указанные координаты. Распечатать эти ходы на экране.

---

Пишу на языке Си.
Не прошу код, но если будет, то круто. Но больше всего хочу, чтобы вы объяснили мне алгоритм решения, даже просто представить не могу, как это решается.

Не занимаюсь копипастом и т.д., я просто хочу разобраться.

Answer (score 3):

По сути доступные ходы являются ребрами графа, а клетки - его вершинами. Кратчайший путь из одной вершины графа в другую можно найти с помощью поиска в ширину (алгоритм поиска в ширину описан многократно и найти его - не проблема).

Так что применяйте поиск в ширину, при этом сам граф можно даже не строить изначально, а только по мере работы алгоритма, когда требуется определить, куда идут ребра из данной вершины - их можно просто вычислять...